# Application Insight not all logs are recording

Tags: azure-application-insights

Recently to find Production issues, I used Application insight and created logs using Telemetry Trace. So, I'm using currently two separate keys one for Dev and one for SIT environment. randomly few logs were missing, I’m not sure what is the issue, no errors.

We just want to log some information and exceptions. No need of request or performance related stuff.

From past three days, at least some part of the logs are missing in between randomly, no errors found. In dev and SIT , concurrent users will hit the APIs. Please suggest do I need to change any configuration.

In Config file I commented Perfcounter part.

And increased MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond to 200.

Using Adaptive sampling. And Telemetry client for logging,
sample code:
telemetry.TrackTrace("", properties) - no severity level mentioned.

Our Application is .NET application, Web API , framework 4.7.

Comment: can you show us the Adaptive sampling settings in the config file? including the IncludedTypes and ExcludedTypes.

Comment: <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <ExcludedTypes>Event;Request;Dependency</ExcludedTypes>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>200</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <IncludedTypes>Trace;Exception;</IncludedTypes>
        </Add>

Comment: I have not changed other part

Comment: If it happens randomly, please remove the Trace from <IncludedTypes>, then the Trace will not be sampled.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will try.

Comment: I'm not sure, can I ask in this thread, I want to log httpcontext response data using application insight, but most of the examples are for .NET core, I want for .NET Framework. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: You'd better raise a new issue and let us know the url:).

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I raised separate request,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444843/logging-request-and-response-to-application-insight

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you have added the `Trace` in `<IncludedTypes></IncludedTypes>` in the config file. Please remove the `Trace` from there, then the `Trace` telemetry data will not be sampled.